# Ответ от сервера AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Я передаю на сервер запрос, в последствии получаем некоторую информацию.
Вопрос в том:
1. Как записать то что приходит- (функция keys) в форму select?

2. Как ответ от сервера записать не в JS , а в php - форму select.

Спасибо.

```js
    <script>
    $('#region_name').change(function(){
       var r  = $("#region_name").val() 
    
    $.post(
  "form_hwac_opr.php",
  {
    r:r
  },
  keys
);
 
function keys(data)
{
  // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
  alert(data);

}
});
   </script>
```

Comment: Друг, у тебя с самим вопросом проблемы. Отформатируй пожалуйста в нормальный вид и объясни, чего ты хочешь добиться.

Тебе приходит скорей всего `json` (общая практика), парсишь его `JSON.parse`  и получаешь объект, в итоге банальным манипулированием `DOM-елементами`, ты можешь подавать данные в нужный `select` или создать новый. `а в php - форму select` - вообще страшные слова, нужно пояснение)

Comment: @Sergey Уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Вы получаете данные из файла `form_hwac_opr.php`. Какие данные Вы оттуда получаете? Вам необходимо при выборе одного селекта - получить данные из файла и поместить их в другой селект, так?